# Definition of $X \times_Y X$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and let $f: X\to Y$.

Questions:

1. What is $X\times_Y X$?
2. What is the map $\Delta_f: X \to X\times_Y X$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_%28category_theory%29

Comment: $\Delta_f$ is just the diagonal inclusion, once you can understand what $X\times_Y X$ is, it is quite intuitive.

Comment: 1. $\{ (x,y) \in X \times X \, : f(x) = f(y) \}$ together with $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ the usual projections from $X \times X$.

Comment: Yes - thanks for your hints, I get it!

Comment: #Andy, are you sure it is true also in the category of topological spaces and not only for the category of sets?

Comment: @Cal, pretty sure. Equalizers are subspaces and Products are cartesian products, so any limit is a subspace of a suitable cartesian product. This makes the diagram commute, so this is the homeomorphic to the fibered product.


Also, you can in general take the (co)limit in Set and put the initial topology on it and you get the (co)limit in Top.

Comment: Actually, to make a colimit in Set be in Top you need the final topology, not the initial. Still, its definition is dual to the other one, so it could have been clear already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space $X\times_Y X$ is a *pullback*, a special case of more general *limits* of topological spaces. See any textbook about category theory, for example Mac Lanes's *Categories for the Working Mathematician*.

Given a diagram maps $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Z\to Y$, the pullback $X\times_Y Z$ is a space which comes together with maps $k:X\times_Y Z\to X$ and $l:X\times_Y Z\to Z$ such that

- $fk=gl$
- For any space $W$ and maps $k':W\to X$ and $l':W\to Z$ such that $fk'=gl'$, there exists a unique map $m:W\to X\times_Y Z$ such that $km=k'$ and $lm=l'$.

It is easy to show that $X\times_Y Z=\{(x,z)\in X\times Z\mid f(x)=g(y)\}$ with the topology as a subspace of the product $X\times Z$, and the maps $k$ and $l$ are the projections. Given $k'$ and $l'$ as above, the unique map $m$ sends $w$ to $(k'(w),l'(w))$.

For an example of a pullback, let $f:X\to Y$ be any map and let $g=i:B\to Y$ be the inclusion of a subspace $B\subseteq Y$. Then $X\times_Y B$ is $\{(x,f(x))\mid f(x)\in B\}$, the part of the graph of $f$ which meets $B$, and this is actually homeomorphic to the preimage $f^{-1}(B)$.

If $f=g:X\to Y$, then $X\times_Y X$ is the subspace of $X\times X$ consisting of those pairs $(x,x')$ such that $f(x)=f(x')$. This is actually nothing but the equivalence relation determined by $f$.

Every map $m:X\to X\times_Y X$ is determined by maps $k$ and $l$ on $X$ such that $fk=fl$. So *the* map $X\to X\times_Y X$ is likely to refer to the map induced by the identity $\mathbf 1_X$, and this map sends $x$ to $(x,x)$.